# Iwant to delete particular key & value from array of object in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: this is my array and i want to delete "**Action**" filed from this array]
How can I remove this action filed from all position. I tried splice method but its does't work for me .

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  array.splice[array[i].Action]
}
```

I also tried delete key word but it  also not work for me.

```
delete array["Action"];
```

can some one help me to find out the solution.

Comment: you try to debug the code and you get the answer! always try to spare some time on code debugging to get more understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not `delete array["Action"]`, but `delete array[i]["Action"]`.

However it will be better to use `map` and create another array with properties except `Action`.

```
array = array.map(({festival, date, day}) => ({ festival, date, day }))
```

Comment: Validate answer for future.

Comment: @vaibhavpancholi accept the answer which work for you by clicking on the green tic mark under the answer. Helps us to know which answer works